# Как сделать автообновляемую таблицу с БД на JS?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Вопрос может быть не понятен....
Так вот:
Нужно сделать вывод с автообновлением из БД в админ - панель. В таблицу. Как, не могу додуматься. Обработчик есть в файле ajax. В таблице 3 стоблца. но один может быть пустым. Подскажите пожалуйста...

Comment: 1) Слишком размыто. 2) Покажите Ваши наработки.

Comment: блин. Просто нужно выводить данные в админ панель на jquery без перезагрузки с оповещанием.
Выводить надо в таблицу. В БД 4 столбца которые надо выводить. строк может быть не ограниченное количество.

Comment: https://datatables.net/

Comment: Вопрос по сути нормальный(можно починить), только вот способов это сделать овер9000

Answer (score 1):

Попытка продемонстрировать как это реализуется в общем случае:

```js
const stubItems = { // Тут будем хранить данные(как будто это база)
  1: {id: 1, title: 'First'},
  2: {id: 2, title: 'Second'},
};

class API { // Класс доступа к нашей "базе", все методы асинхронные, чтобы переход на реальный API был наиболее легким
  get(id) {
    return new Promise((ok, fail) => {
      return stubItems[id] ? ok(stubItems[id]) : fail();
    });
  }
  list() {
    return new Promise(ok => ok(Object.keys(stubItems).map(id => stubItems[id])));
  }
}

class Table { // Класс таблицы с данными
  constructor(api, id) { // Передаём объект API и идентификатор таблицы
    this.api = api;
    this.tbody = document.querySelector(`#${id} tbody`); 
  }
  clear() { // Очистка строк таблицы
    [...this.tbody.querySelectorAll('tr')].forEach(tr => tr.remove());
  }
  addRow(id, title) { // Конструирование строки и добавление её в таблицу
    const tr = document.createElement('tr');
    const tdId = document.createElement('td');
    const tdTitle = document.createElement('td');
    tdId.textContent = id;
    tdTitle.textContent = title;
    tr.appendChild(tdId);
    tr.appendChild(tdTitle);
    this.tbody.appendChild(tr);
  }
  update() { // Обновление содержимого таблицы из API
    this.clear(); // Очищаем таблицу до запроса. Вероятно, более коректным будет очищать её после запроса, +проверять, может и не изменилось ничего.
    this.api.list() // Запрашиваем данные из базы
      .then(res => res.forEach(row => this.addRow(row.id, row.title)));
  }
}

const api = new API();
const table = new Table(api, 'data-table');
table.update();
setInterval(() => table.update(), 1000);

// Имитируем обновление базы
setTimeout(() => stubItems[4] = {id: 4, title: 'Forth'}, 1500);
setTimeout(() => {delete stubItems[2];}, 5000);
```

```html
<table id="data-table">
  <thead>
    <tr><th>Id</th><th>Title</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, мне надо просто создавать каждый раз при получении данных объект (элемент) таблицы, и туда просто напросто вставлять полученные обработчиком данные?
$('#wrapper').append('<a href="http://google.com">Гугли!</a>');
Такой вариант вроде более будет удобным нет?)

Comment: Вам нужно изменить содержимое вашей страницы на основе полученных данных. В случае с таблицей - это удаление/добавление строк. Можно на сервере генерировать готовые элементы HTML, но это плохо масштабируемо - гораздо лучше получать сырые данные и на их основе менять DOM. В jquery действительно много синтаксического сахара для изменения страницы, но лично мне больше по душе конструировать сами объекты, а не html для дальнейшего парсинга.

Comment: неособо понял(((

Comment: Код в ответе почитали? Как работает в целом понятно? Теперь представьте, что API ходит за данными не в массив в js, а в Ваш backend на php. Для класса Table неважно, где API берёт данные - их формат не меняется. Получив нужные данные, класс Table может обновить страницу(таблицу) в соответствии с данными, которые он получил. В моём случае мы просто вычищаем таблицу, и создаём новые строки с новыми данными.